# How to limit the number of results from find?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I would like to do something like:

```
find ./ -name "*.jpg" -nbresult 50 -exec cp {} /50randomsjpgfrommyharddrive
```

I can use `head` and `xargs`, but with `-print0`, `head` doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU head has an option called -z for changing the line terminator to NUL, which can be used for this task as shown below.

```
find -name '*.jpg' -print0 \
| head -z -n 50 \
| xargs -0 cp -t /destination
```

Comment: When was `head -z` introduced? Not in coreutils 8.21 (Ubuntu 14.04LTS) though I see that 8.28 has it.

Comment: @alaniwi Ubuntu14.04 is not LTS anymore, it's reached its EOL. My coreutils version is 8.31

Comment: in case you want to sort (or randomize), `sort` also has a `-z` flag, so you can do e.g. `find . -print0 | sort -z | head -zn 50 | ...` if you want the top 50, sorted alphabetically.  Or get 50 random ones: `find . -print0 | sort -zR | head -zn 50 | ...`

Answer (score 3):

Provided that you do not have newlines in the filenames, `-print0` is unnecessary, and you can have instead:

```
find ./ -name "*.jpg" | head -n 50 | xargs -d'\n' -n1 -I'{}' cp '{}' /50randomsjpgfrommyharddrive
```

In this command, the `-d'\n'` will make `xargs` delimit on newlines. Other whitespace in filenames, which would by default be treated as a delimiter by `xargs`, are then not a problem.

Alternatively, if you still need to use `-print0`, the following command line incorporates a filter which is analogous to `head -n 50` but is based on null delimiters (rather than newlines) on its input and output.  Note that `-0` is needed on `xargs` in this case.

```
find ./ -name "*.jpg" -print0 | perl -p0e 'exit if $i++ == 50' | xargs -0 -n1 -I'{}' cp '{}' /50randomsjpgfrommyharddrive
```